# Backup Restore SharePOint Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, backup, restore

I have about 20 site collections in a web application and i want to restore those into a new web application . Can some one suggest me whats the best approach to do this ..

I have tried the following approach to backup the site collection using power shell and restore it using the same ,but i found out that all the URLs in the documents libraries are getting updated so i had to edit each individual item which will be quite complex,is there something i should write on the power shell script to prevent this..

Can some one suggest me whats the best approach to do this ..

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by URLs are getting updated?

Comment: Yes sure .. I Have a document library which have absolute urls to all the site collections in the web applications.Once i did a restore the urls are getting updated for eg : my old url is http://intranet/community/onecoommunity after restore to new web application it is changing to http://mynewintranet/community/onecoommunity (Where mynewintranet is the new web application where i restored the site collection)

Comment: So what would you like it to be per item?

Comment: I want it to be previous URL only instead of getting updated..

Comment: @Anvil, can you provide more detail, maybe with some screen shots?  A temporary solution could be to use the URL rewrite module and just implement some re-direct logic, then follow that up with a script that updates your URL's (note, rewrites are not supported in SharePoint, but redirects work fine).